# Creating a line through TicTacToe buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is it possible to make a line through `Button`s in a tictactoe, when there are three `Button`s with the same symbol e.g.

[image: picture of TicTacToe board]

[image]

[image]

If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Yes, that is possible

Comment: Did you try anything or you just want game codes?

Comment: I just want to know if it can be done and which build in classes I will need to use. But an example is more then welcomed.

Comment: Nothing impossible in java SON!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way it can be done is with some `boolean` logic and a custom `JButton` class and some custom painting. For instance in the example below, there a `leftRight` flag. If there is a horizontal tic tac toe, the `leftRight` flag will be raised, causing the line to be draw in each of the buttons in the tic tac toe

Forgive my tic tac toe programming logic, it's not a final game product. It only gives an example of the top row tic tac toe of O's. But I'm sure you can figure out the logic for the other type of tic tac toe's. For instance, for a diagonal, you can have a `leftDiag` flag and if raised, it would paint `drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())`

Play with it. ENJOY!

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TTTButtons {

    ImageIcon oooIcon;
    MyButton[][] buttons = new MyButton[3][3];
    JPanel gamePanel;

    public TTTButtons() {
        oooIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/ooooo.png"));
        gamePanel = createGamePanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
        frame.add(gamePanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private JPanel createGamePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new MyButton(oooIcon);
                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TTTButtons();
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyButton extends JButton {

        Image oooImage;
        boolean leftRight = false;
        boolean clicked = false;
        boolean ooo = false;

        boolean tictactoe = false;

        public MyButton(ImageIcon oooImage) {
            this.oooImage = oooImage.getImage();
            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    clicked = true;
                    ooo = true;
                    if (buttons[0][0].clicked && buttons[0][1].clicked && buttons[0][2].clicked) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            buttons[0][i].leftRight = true;
                            buttons[0][i].tictactoe = true;
                            buttons[0][i].repaint();
                        } 
                        return;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (clicked) {
                if (ooo) {
                    g.drawImage(oooImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
                }
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
            if (tictactoe) {
                if (leftRight) {
                    g.drawLine(0, (int) (getHeight() / 2), getWidth(), (int) (getHeight() / 2));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return oooImage == null ? new Dimension(100, 100)
                    : new Dimension(oooImage.getWidth(this), oooImage.getHeight(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you know the line being created, is it an image or line from the graphic / paint class?

Comment: btw, i am getting an null pointer error, anyway of solving this.

Comment: It's a line that I'm drawing. Look at the `paintComponent` method in the `MyButton` class. There's a `tictactoe` flag that is raised that will draw the line

Comment: Yeah, make sure you are using the right image path. In my case my `resources` is a package in the `src`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JFrame then it is easy. Try this:

```
if(shape1==shape2 && shape2==shape3){
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 250, 260);
        g2.draw(lin);
    }
}
```

Of course the coordinates depend on where your shape is.

Comment: yep, i am using a JFrame.

Comment: hi, on the paint keyword, i am getting an error oid is an invalid type for the variable paint, do i need to import something for that?

Comment: Try these imports: import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

Comment: It should be working with these imports. I cannot understand why it is not.

Comment: it gives me error on these.   public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  the keyword paint is underline in red, saying the error oid is an invalid type for the variable paint.

Comment: I'd stay away from painting on top-level containers like JFrame as they already carry the burden of painting components. Instead use a `JPanel` or a `JComponent` and override `paintComponent`

Comment: Also the if statement should be _inside_ the `paint` method if anything. You can't declare a method inside an `if` block.

Comment: no luck, I already had JPanel and all the content on the JPanel and even putting the if statement inside the paint method didn't help. Is there a video guide i can watch onto, maybe i am doing something wrong.